# Laravel 5.8: Loading images not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and in this project I want to show some images that I had uploaded through database like this:

[image]

And at the view, I tried this:

```
<div class="text-center" style="background-image: url('public\images\tavana\{{ $images[0]->path }}');height: 220px;">
```

But the problem is the image does not load!

However the image already exists at the this directory:

```
public\images\tavana\imagename.jpg
```

And other data such as `title`, `subtitle` properly shows up.

So how to properly show the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `asset` to generate url

```
<div class="text-center" style="background-image: url('{{asset('images/tavana/'.$images[0]->path)}}');height: 220px;background-repeat: no-repeat">
```

also not sure why you  are accessing 0th index `$images[0]->path`  instead you can return `first()` so it will be `$images->path`

If you have multiple then use loop

Answer (score 0):

You can't try:

```
 <div class="text-center" style="background-image: url({{url('/')}}.'public/images/tavana/{{ $images[0]->path }}');height: 220px;background-repeat: no-repeat">
```